# How do I send work samples too large to attach through an application interface?

Tags: job-search, applications

I have applied for jobs through the company's website and/ or sites like Indeed or craigslist jobs. Unfortunately, many times the files(PDF's that are production print quality) are too large due to the fact that they're so graphically intense. What is the best way to handle files that surpass file size limitations in an application interface?

Comment: Edited to clarify title and make the question align with site standards.  Good first question.

Comment: What kind of files are you attaching that are so large?

Comment: Do you need the extra resolution in the large version - can't you create a version with lower-res graphics for distribution? Unless e.g. they're PDF samples designed to be printed, but that seems over the top for a job application. Could you host the large versions somewhere (e.g. dropbox) and send links to that in the application?

Comment: The files are pdfs and ARE designed to be printed. I'm not sure what others would think about me sending a dropbox link (in fact many companies have policies prohibiting them opening anything in a link of any sort, unfortunately)

Comment: But do the companies you are applying to need to be printing them? A low res screen version should be sufficient to demonstrate your skill as a designer, etc and you can include a note that full resolution versions are available upon request.

Comment: @EvanSteinbrenner Not sure how to do that without changing to jpg, changing res, and returning it to a PDF format. Not that it would really work, the file size limits are typically 1.23 mb or smaller.

Comment: Without a lot more details I can't say for sure but my preferred option would always be to go back to the source program and recreate the PDF using a lower quality pdf preset. Use a web quality instead of print quality preset etc. If that isn't possible you could re-pdf it by printing the PDF to a PDF printer and use a lower quality preset at that point.

If the file is still too large then you might need to consider if you need to send the entire file. If it is a 20 page PDF do you really need all 20 pages or is 1 or 2 sufficient to demonstrate your work in that example.

Comment: If you've got Acrobat itself there's a ['Save as Other > Optimized PDF'](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/optimizing-pdfs-acrobat-pro.html) that'll do all this for you, though I realise there's plenty of other ways to make PDFs than Acrobat these days.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that's an idea. Have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @EvanSteinbrenner the things I'm attaching are complete products. A 32 page self published book (to show I can handle large projects), a 6 page brochure, and a 2 page (front and back) tri-fold brochure.

Comment: How about you produce two PDFs. One print quality and one e-mail quality (e.g. higher compression). Most software allows adjusting the quality of the output file. It may not look as good printed out, but that's a necessary trade-off. The text should still be readable in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My view is that you need to contact them and ask.

Unless you are the first person in this role they have ever hired (in which case they may not be able to judge the big files) they will have some kind of method for submitting these files, either directly (say Dropbox as stated in your question) or via flash drive etc.

If they don't,  they aren't expecting files of the size you are trying to send and you should still contact them to understand their requirements (a vital skill in any job anyway).

Comment: Most companies have a "do not contact" rule in regards to job applications nowadays -- or you simply can't find their contact info (basically the moment you contact them you disqualify yourself from the running). The caveat is to craigslist ads, I could send multiple emails explaining that my samples are of a size that if I don't send them in multiple emails they'll bounce back.

Comment: Speaking as a candidate and hiring manager,  I'll bet you can phone the general number and ask to speak to someone in their recruitment team to advise. The "Do Not Contact"  is about not bugging them about you as an applicant,  a legitimate question will not get you knocked out (and if it does, you wouldn't want to work there anyway)